# How can I get a vscode terminal in an extension by name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In one of my own vscode extensions I created a terminal `MyTerminal`. Now I'd like to get the instance of this terminal in one of my regsitered commands in my extension. How can I get the terminal by name `MyTerminal`?

Answer (score 1):

You can the currently open terminals via [`window.terminals`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window). Each instance of [`Terminal` has a `name` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Terminal).

You should be able to access your terminal by iterating through the `window.terminals` and checking to see which one has `MyTerminal` as its name.